# How to aggregate doc_ inner-hits of nested objects in elasticsearch query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I tried to aggregate over the inner-hits, but the code aggregates on all the docs. I need aggregation on each document inner-hits instead of global aggregation. How do I code it?

I have tried this code after the query

```
"aggs": {
    "jobs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "departures"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "departures_only": {
          "filter": {           
            "range" : {
                    "departures.eb_price": {
                      "gte" : 90000,
                      "lte" : 100000
                    }
                  }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "start_price" : { "min" : { "field" : "departures.eb_price" } },
            "start_date" : { "min" : { "field" : "departures.start_date"} }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The actual result is

```
    "jobs" : {
      "doc_count" : 55,
      "departures_only" : {
        "doc_count" : 55,
        "start_price" : {
          "value" : 93440.0
        },
        "start_date" : {
          "value" : 1.5696288E12,
          "value_as_string" : "28 Sep 2019"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But the actual result should show this aggregation for each document instead of the complete docs in the query results. Because the aggregations to be run on each individual document's inner-hits.

Any suggestions? I am just a beginner in elasticsearch

Comment: it is not possible to aggregate data on a per-document basis, only on a per result set basis. Can you show a sample document and what you'd like to see in the results?

Comment: The document is too big. it contains name, text and in nested types it contains many objects with price and date. After query I need to extract min. price and starting date from each document.

Comment: Well, trim it down a bit to show only the relevant parts. You can also share via [gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anandthati/9892eae3b72b846b710dbbc6074daca4 .  attaching the gist link to trimmed document

Comment: Thanks and based on that document, what would you like to see in the results?

Comment: Like mentioned before.. i need to get aggregations for each document. In gist document there are 3 nested objects under departures. After query I need to get the min.price and starting date from such documents.

Comment: Why don't you create that data at indexing time since you have all the data at hand already?

Comment: That will change every time with different filter queries. I can set min.price and starting date among all the departures in nested objects. but when applied filter with different dates it shows up related departures in inner-hits, which may not contain the min.price and starting date.

Comment: Oh I see... If you add a top-level terms aggregation on the `_id` field then the sub-aggregations would be performed on a per-document basis. Can you test that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199884/discussion-between-anand-thati-and-val).